# How to prevent the change of the height and width of the listbox at runtime

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

In Main window, I have Grid in which a list box and content control is available.

I have set the SizeToContent property of the window to "WidthAndHeight" and also window can be resizable.

Listbox has different control names as items, on selection of an item in the list box, Content control will be filled with respective user control.

I have controls of different sizes, few of them are small and other are big in size.  As I have set  SizeToContent property to "WidthAndHeight". The user controls are fitting, that is the window will change its width and height dynamically by fitting the user control.

Now the issue is - in one of my control I have "ListBox" , which changes its height and width based on the content (am fetching the data from database) of the listbox without  appearing the  Horizontal and vertical scroll bars. How to stop this behaviour ?

Am looking for the solution to fix the listbox behaviour where it instead increasing height and width of the list box , Horizontal and vertical scroll bars should appear.

Please do respond ASAP.

Forgot few points, after loading the first control loaded am setting the SizeToContent to "Manual". 
But on loading the second large control ,the control is not fitting in the existing space of the window.

Initially, when window is loaded first control will be appeared which is small in size.
Now when I am trying to load second control which is very big in size compare to first control
As shown below the control is loaded but a scrollbar is appeared which is not acceptable.

First control is fitted very well as I set SizeToContent property of the window to **WidthAndHeight**, 
which is changed to **Manual** once after the window is loaded.

Comment: Forgot few points, after loading the first control loaded am setting the SizeToContent to "Manual". But on loading the second large control ,the control is not fitting in the exist space of the window.

Comment: could you post some screens? what you are facing and what you want

Comment: *Forgot few points*... well don't put them in comments where they are easily missed. Edit your question and put your forgotten points there instead.

Comment: I have updated my post with few more points.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a `ListBox` from being resized by its contents, simply constrain its `Width` and `Height`. You can do that by putting it into a `Grid` with specific `RowDefinition`s and `ColumnDefinition`s, or by simply setting the `ListBox.Width` and `ListBox.Height` properties directly:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Width="400" Height="800" />
```

Alternatively, you could always set the `ListBox.MaxWidth` and `ListBox.MaxHeight` properties instead:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" MaxWidth="400" MaxHeight="800" />
```

The `ScrollBar`s should automatically appear once the content grows larger than these maximum values, but you can also set them explicitly using the [`ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ... />
```

Comment: we tried all these. Exact scenario is - Initially, when window is loaded first control will be appeared which is small in size.
Now when I am trying to load second control which is very big in size compare to first control
As shown below the control is loaded but a scrollbar is appeared which is not acceptable.

First control is fitted very well as I set SizeToContent property of the window to **WidthAndHeight**, 
which is changed to **Manual** once after the window is loaded.  Max width and Height will not suit for us, as window can be resizable.

Comment: You are causing your own problem by setting the `SizeToContent` property of the `Window` to `Manual`. You simply can't add a large control into a small space without `ScrollBar`s.